# Why parent and child borders do not overlap?

Tags: html, css

I tried to create a simple layout using plain html and css:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="top bordered"></div>
        <div class="bott bordered"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right bordered">
    </div>
</div>

.container {height: 500px; background-color: #eeeeee;}
.left {float: left; width: 49%; height: 80%; position: relative;}
.right {float: right; width: 50%; height: 80%;}
.bordered {border: 1px solid #aaaaaa; border-radius: 5px;}
.top {height: 20%; width: 100%; position: absolute; bottom: 0;}
.bott {height: 30%; width: 100%;}
```

Please take a look http://jsfiddle.net/SLfHf/.
I want two bottom borders (at left and right) to be displayed at the same height. But as you can see left one is a bit higher. Investigating this I found out that children borders do not overlap parent borders, even if there're no any paddings and margins.
So the question is: why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just how the default CSS box model (called `content-box`) works.  A box's size is equal to its specified width/height dimensions + padding + border.

`box-sizing: border-box` is a CSS property that changes the box model so that padding and border are inside the specified dimensions rather than added to them (e.g. specified width/height - padding - border).  Using this has become increasingly popular in the last few years as many consider it an easier box model to work with, and it arguably makes responsive design a bit easier.  All you need to do is add this to your stylesheet:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Borders never collapse with adjacent borders regardless of box model or context.  You need to set borders individually (i.e. `border-top: 1px solid #000`) to accomplish that behavior.

The only time adjacent boxes have any kind of collapse property outside of tables is in some specific situations adjacent margins will collapse: [more info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include borders within hight/weidth of a boxe, you should use :

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing0
(prefix might be needed :) )

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems to be a solution. But anyway, I can't understand default behavior. If we have two nested divs, inner has width/height set to 100%... why they have different borders?

Comment: @doob , borders have a size. it always stands on the outside.Box-sizing tells to include it or not within given size. You can use box-shadow to fake borders inside or use outline. You needed to follow the link given to learn by yourself